# Falta traducir texto "Rollback"

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

Si visitáis cualquier historial de ediciones en el cuál se haya hecho una reversión veréis que el nombre es "Rollback" ([ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/21735/revisions)) en la descripción de la edición.

Ahora mismo aparece:

> Rollback to Revision N

Debería aparecer:

> Revertir a Revisión N

Comment: Me parece que "Rollback" se utiliza como verbo en este caso, por lo cual propondría que la traducción sea "Revertir a Revisión N".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En este caso el texto estaba directamente en inglés en el código, sin posibilidad por tanto de ser traducido. He cambiado el código y de paso he traducido el texto.